# how can I add rectangle in blank slide

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am using apache poi to create ppt.
Till now I am able to add line as shape in blank slides but unable to add rectangle in it. I am not getting how can I proceed to draw rectangle in blank slide.

Thanks for all suggestions in advance.

EDIT:

Below I am posting code drawing line. I have drawn 4 lines which are upper horizontal,right vertical, lower horizontal, left vertical. It is working fine but I need to draw rectangle instead of 4 lines.

// draws square

```
        java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double upperHorizontalPath = new java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double();
        upperHorizontalPath.moveTo(20, 200);
        upperHorizontalPath.lineTo(230, 200);
        upperHorizontalPath.closePath();
        XSLFFreeformShape upperHorizontalShape = indexslide.createFreeform();
        upperHorizontalShape.setPath(upperHorizontalPath);
        upperHorizontalShape.setLineWidth(3);
        upperHorizontalShape.setLineColor(Color.BLACK);

        java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double rightVerticalPath = new java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double();
        rightVerticalPath.moveTo(230, 200);
        rightVerticalPath.lineTo(230, 300);
        rightVerticalPath.closePath();
        XSLFFreeformShape rightVerticalShape = indexslide.createFreeform();
        rightVerticalShape.setPath(rightVerticalPath);
        rightVerticalShape.setLineWidth(3);
        rightVerticalShape.setLineColor(Color.BLACK);

        java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double lowerHorizontalPath = new java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double();
        lowerHorizontalPath.moveTo(230, 300);
        lowerHorizontalPath.lineTo(20, 300);
        lowerHorizontalPath.closePath();
        XSLFFreeformShape lowerHorizontalShape = indexslide.createFreeform();
        lowerHorizontalShape.setPath(lowerHorizontalPath);
        lowerHorizontalShape.setLineWidth(3);
        lowerHorizontalShape.setLineColor(Color.BLACK);

        java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double leftVerticalPath = new java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double();
        leftVerticalPath.moveTo(20, 300);
        leftVerticalPath.lineTo(20, 200);
        leftVerticalPath.closePath();
        XSLFFreeformShape leftVerticalShape = indexslide.createFreeform();
        leftVerticalShape.setPath(leftVerticalPath);
        leftVerticalShape.setLineWidth(3);
        leftVerticalShape.setLineColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help to create rectangle shape in slide.

XSLFTextBox lowerTextShape = locationSlide.createTextBox();

```
                        ((XSLFSimpleShape) lowerTextShape).setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 100, 600, 80));
                        ((XSLFSimpleShape) lowerTextShape).setAnchor(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 385, 240, 110));
                        ((XSLFSimpleShape) lowerTextShape).setLineColor(Color.WHITE);
                        ((XSLFSimpleShape) lowerTextShape).setLineWidth(3);
```